# Given a string consisting of charachters, find the frequency of each digit

Tags: c

In the below code num1 is the output and the num2 is the expected output.
What is the difference in (isdigit(s[i]) > 0) and (isdigit(s[i]) >= 0)?

```
int main()
{

    char s[1000];
    int num1[10] = { 0 }, num2[10], c;
    scanf("%s", s);
    int len = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        if (isdigit(s[i]) >= 0) {
            c = (s[i]) - '0';
            num1[c] += 1;
        }
        if (isdigit(s[i]) > 0) {
            c = (s[i]) - '0';
            num2[c] += 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", num1[i]); //num1 is the output
        printf("%d ", num2[i]); //num2 is the expected output
    }

    return 0;
}
```

STDIN:8g614eggv7n388564l82nl6f35826hrzd533380b7870n4954497308f03wsx6zyr45025845zz55x7576631425l311cj4n9u29f4xje02l35t31m6me078bx421c24cocx83e438g88d069cc39bn6292033q055kk81m4f82798h7pt031mv530g4v7519h6g78z34p228f9z6067emv47e83uj805q805d572k18h077q6zzo22f35k22631l5j6n8fz0u583xkuu392613478x8823119241o6802910551sm8w9or6v78443c8wt63i3ft21d548p79h14i26k65qhbs79h65su27l1waz62m7l155bib1a2w401b8j7s2i719i68tr60492f685g7lx96i077775kq9436s6s6h81f827624583m894314vjvd41385ww0639e6xs8wzn6362a0029233j99097be0124408o90c861281jgu3168765af270z47e208bclp3845799e4p2710i231h

STDOUT:
num1:32 32 39 37 34 34 40 37 46 30
num2:32 33 40 40 35 35 39 36 48 29

Comment: Pick one language: C or C++. The code looks like C.

Comment: Check out minimum reproducible code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Read the documentation. `isdigit()` returns zero if the character is not a digit, and non-zero if it's a digit. You shouldn't use `>` in the condition at all, there's reason for it to be positive or negative.

Comment: Just use `if (isdigit(s[i]))`, you shouldn't compare with anything.

Comment: `isdigit(s[i]) >= 0` is always true (unless it is returning a negative number for truth, which is quite unlikely, but not forbidden).

Comment: Unrelated: When you see a `<=` or `>=` in a for loop condition, for example, `for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)`, look closely to make sure you don't have an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 3):

They're both wrong.

Per [**7.4.1 Character classification functions**, paragraph 1 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1p1):

> The functions in this subclause return nonzero (true) if and only if the value of the argument c conforms to that in the description of the function.

Values less than zero are still "true", so both implementations will miss digits where `isdigit()` happens to return a negative value - which is non-zero value albeit one that is less than zero.

But

```
if(isdigit(s[i]) >= 0)
{
    c = (s[i]) - '0';
    num1[c] += 1;
}
```

is more wrong in that it will return true for all non-digit characters where `isdigit()` returns zero.

**To summarize:**

The `>` implementation will miss some digits.

The `>=` implementation will miss some digits and count all non-digits as digits.

Answer (score 2):

The function `isdigit` has the following [prototype](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/):

```
int isdigit (int c);
```

This means the function takes an `int` as an argument, and returns an `int` as an answer.

If the value returned is zero, the argument is not a digit. If the value is not zero, the argument is a digit.

The test `isdigit(s[i]) >= 0` is almost certainly not sensible or correct, because this can account for both *some* true and false conditions. The other test you use is incorrect, as well, as it can leave out some true results.

A more correct test for digits would be `isdigit(s[i]) != 0`, following the definition, to account for conditions where both negative and positive non-zero integers are returned from `isdigit`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply use the function the wrong way.  `isdigit` returns a non zero value (it can be positive or negative) if the parameter is a digit.

There are some minor problems in the code as well.

```
int main(void)
{

    char s[1000];
    int num1[10] = { 0, }, c;

    scanf("%999s", s);
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) {
            num1[(s[i]) - '0']++;;
        }

    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", num1[i]); //num1 is the output
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h9qKqdvcK

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> The isdigit() function shall return non-zero if
> c is a decimal digit; otherwise, they shall return 0.

Which means when you check `if (isdigit(s[i]) >= 0)`, that will be true regardless `s[i]` is a digit or not. What you probably need is,

```
if (isdigit(s[i]) != 0) {
            c = (s[i]) - '0';
            num1[c] += 1;
        }
```

The other `if` block is wrong, `num2[]` array is uninitialized and will overflow in the event of a letter found , e.g `'a' - '0'`.

You might also want to pass an `unsigned char` to functions like `isdigit()`, since anything not re presentable as `unsigned char` will result in `Undefined Behavior`.

> The c argument is an int, the value of which the application
> shall ensure is a character representable as an unsigned char or
> equal to the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any
> other value, the behavior is undefined.